# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array with databases

Tags: php, html, mysql

I cannot figure out what is wrong here, i'm trying to display my database results and it gives me this error, what is wrong with?

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","fakultet");
if ($mysqli->error) {
    die("Greska :".$mysqli->error);
}
$upit = "Select * from student WHERE sifra>165";
$rez = mysqli_query($mysqli,$upit);

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th>BrInd</th>
            <th>Prezime</th>
            <th>Ime</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>sifra</th>
        </tr>

        <?php

        while ($kokoš=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$rez['BrInd']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rez['Prezime']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rez['Ime']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rez['status']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rez['sifra']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            # code...
        }
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not an expert i just want to learn it, but it's giving me a lot of headaches.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `mysqli_error($mysqli)` on the query shows what? and error reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fetched the row from the result set into a variable called `$kokoš` so it is that variable that contains the column data.

```
while ($kokoš=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$kokoš['BrInd']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$kokoš['Prezime']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$kokoš['Ime']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$kokoš['status']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$kokoš['sifra']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    # code...
}
```

Comment: @RiggasFolly, thanks alot for the help, I am blind, cannot believe I didn't notice that, when you're frustrated you miss the simplest things, once again, thank you!